# Pagination with django nonrel search

Tags: django, pagination, django-nonrel

I'm using the [full text search](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search) functionality of django nonrel. I'm trying to do pagination with this code;

```
results = search(MyModel, keyword)[10:20]
```

but it returns no records. There was no problem when i use [0:10]; the first 10 rows returned. If i use [5:20]; the records from 10 to 20 returns. It seams like nonrel applies the slicing twice. Do you have any suggestions about how to use pagination with django nonrel search?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that slicing in django appengine is some kind of slow. Instead, please consider using cursor

```
from djangoappengine.db.utils import get_cursor, set_cursor

num_items=5
query=search(MyModel,request.GET['key_words'])

next=request.GET.get('next')
if next:
     query=set_cursor(query,next)

results=query[0:num_items]
next=get_cursor(results)        
return render_to_response(template_name,{
                    'result':results,
                    'next':next,
                    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You even can hold a previous cursor to go backward.

Hope it help